# Scala remote method injection

Tags: scala

I have a requirement, I have a method, which takes another function. I want to get the result of this parameter function in my caller. 
I have created a code snippet for this scenario:

```
class ProcessHandler {

  def executeInstructions(x:String=>Array[String])
  {
     //print the resultant list here

 } 
}

object ProcessHandlerMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val handler = new ProcessHandler
  handler.executeInstructions(   instruction)
 }

 def instruction(x:String):Array[String] =
  {
  List("words", "from", "book").toArray
  }
}
```

This call **handler.executeInstructions(   instruction)** will be made by another process. Here I am using main method to test it out.

Here is what I do not know:

- How can I print the result of parameter function
- If I have to expose this method *executeInstructions()* to client side, what is the best approach? Here we will not be passing text instructions, rather a function similar to *instruction()*.

Thanks

Updated: From the response received, my code is updated to

```
class ProcessHandler {

 def executeInstructions(x:String=>Array[String])
 {
 //print the resultant list here
  val result = x("some string here")

//this array will be sent to another service
// dispatcher.dispatch(result)
} 
}
```

My requirements are updated:

- How can I print the result of parameter function : **Done**
- If I have to expose this method executeInstructions() to client side, what is the best approach? Here we will not be passing text instructions, rather a function similar to instruction(). **Pending**

The client interface has will work as below:
1. client will be calling executeInstructions() remotely and pass function as parameter. 
2. InstructionId will be passed to the injected function, the resultant array will be dispatched to another service.